# preventDefault when user inputs particular keys in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, preventdefault

I am writing a script so that, whenever the user types into the textarea some particular keyboard keys, using a map, I am showing the replacement of that key, I defined, if any exists.

If there is no mapping, I want to have the default behavior.

So the mapping is like `map[oldKey] = newKey;`

My code works fine if I start by typing keys that are mapped.(It correctly shows the replacements). Although If I press an unmapped key, and then try a mapped one, it doesn't work anymore.

I think I am not using correctly the `preventDefault()` in some way.

check my  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqabq4qg/)!

Thanks

Comment: preventDefault is to prevent the default event a browser takes when an event takes place. For example, when a link is clicked to prevent is from browsing there. Try using an if/else statement instead. In the feature, also add the code of your question to your question instead of just linking the fiddle, thanks!

Comment: Hi Thew. Do you mean something like the comment ? thanks for the advice

Comment: Yes! The answer by @rahulmr below is a good solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<textarea id="area" class="textbox"></textarea>

var greekArr = "ΑΒΨΔΕΦΓΗΙ ΚΛΜΝΟΠ ΡΣΤΘΩ ΧΥΖ";
    var map = {};
    for (var i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
        map[i] = greekArr.charAt(i - 65);
    }

    $('textarea').on('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode in map) {
            var div = document.getElementById('area');
            div.value = div.value + map[e.keyCode];
            return false;
        }


    });
```

Comment: Thanks rahulmr for the answer. Your hack around almost work despite the fact that the compined keys like ctrl+a ctrl+x etc don't work.

Comment: @NicolasNicolas To solve that, try adding multiple events that can trigger your replacements, like instead of just `keydown` try `keydown keyup keypress`, a documentation on the difference between those 3 events is noted [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var greekArr = "ΑΒΨΔΕΦΓΗΙ ΚΛΜΝΟΠ ΡΣΤΘΩ ΧΥΖ";
var map = {};
for (var i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
    map[i] = greekArr.charAt(i - 65);
}

$('textarea').on('keydown', function (e) {
   var textArea = $(this)[0];
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        textArea.value = textArea.value + map[key];
        return false;
    }
});
```